# error with web service: There is an error in XML document

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2012, wsdl

I received a web service which provides a wsdl, and when I test it in SoapUI it runs fine and returns the data back, but when I add the WSDL file as web service in Visual studio and then test it, it throws the error below. After looking in the inner exception saw this:

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
       at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffe
    r& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
```

In Visual Studio's reference.cs file I saw that the company property is delcared as type string but it contains XmlElementAttribute which I think converts it to integer.

I changed the data type from string to integer but it still did not work.
I can't debug the code as I have only the wsdl file in my dev machine and the web service provided to me is not accessible from outside the client's network.

What should I do to solve this?

---

Code from Reference.cs

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="integer")]
    public string Company {
        get {
            return this.companyField;
        }
        set {
            this.companyField = value;
        }
    }
```

---

```
Error Message:
There is an error in XML document (1, 491).

Error StackTrace
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, St
ring encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, St
ring encodingStyle)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClie
ntMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCal
l)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodN
ame, Object[] parameters)
   at GetArticles_Console.IHWebReference.GetArticlesFromToDate.SHA0
03bis_GetArticlesFromToDateOperation(GetArticleDataRequestTypeSHA003Bi
s_GetArticleDataRequestElement GetArticleDataRequestElement) in C:\Use
rs\sp_install\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\GetArticles_Console\VDVGe
tArticles_Console\Web References\IHWebReference\Reference.cs:line 79
   at GetArticles_Console.Program.InvokeGetArticlesFromToDateOperat
ion() in C:\Users\sp_install\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\GetArticle
s_Console\GetArticles_Console\Program.cs:line 58
   at GetArticles_Console.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\sp_install\
Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\GetArticles_Console\GetArticles_Cons
ole\Program.cs:line 18

Error InnerException
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffe
r& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseDecimal(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberForma
tInfo numfmt)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderSHA003
bis_GetArticlesFromToDate.Read3_Item(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderSHA003
bis_GetArticlesFromToDate.Read4_Item(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderSHA003
bis_GetArticlesFromToDate.Read6_Item()
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer3.Des
erialize(XmlSerializationReader reader)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, St
ring encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)

Error Source
System.Xml
```

---

First line from the response data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><n4:Envelope xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:n="http://www.informatica.com/wsdl/" xmlns:n4="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:n5="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><n4:Body><n:SHA003Bis_GetArticleDataResponse><n:SHA003Bis_GetArticleDataResponseElement><n:Articles><n:Article><n:MMITNO>L8035.145      </n:MMITNO><n:MMITDS>Print Saint-Tropez</n:MMITDS>
```

The string above is 498 chars long. 491th char is the colon ":" here `</n:MMITDS>`

Comment: "I changed the data type from string to integer" why would you do that, if it's meant to be a string? What's the value that's failing? Is it actually meant to be a number or not?

Comment: I am not sure what is the value that is failing. As I said above, I can't debug the code. 

The method is expecting three arguments for its parameters and one of them is specified as `Integer` in XSD, but in Visual Studio is it created as String Type. Based on the inner exception the error is thrown during the conversion from string to integer.

Comment: You can find out what's failing by looking at the XML based on the error message - look at character 491 of the first line...

Comment: Jon, I have added the WSDL code in my post above. But the `error source` indicates that the error happened in `System.xml`

Comment: It's not in the WSDL - it's in the data that it's reading (as far as I can tell).

Comment: I am not sure which other data you are referring

Comment: The data that's being parsed when it fails. You should be able to see that using a network trace such as Wireshark.

Comment: I used Fiddler to capture the data and there I get the data but I get an exception in my console application or in .Net Web Service tool. It seems that the webservice itself is not failing but how the code interprets it is failing. See my update above for the first line. It contains only 250 chars.

Comment: Right, so you've got the data. Now look at it - look at what's on line 1, at character 491. I suspect it's not an integer, and the client code is trying to parse an integer, hence the failure... (I don't see any update in the post... you last updated it 22 hours ago)

Comment: it is there. I updated it. Look for "First line from the response data"

Comment: It's there *now*, but it wasn't when you said it was before (or when I added the comment). And what you've posted wouldn't be the first line of the response data - it doesn't even start with `<`, nor does it have any element or attribute names... what you've posted just isn't XML.

Comment: I updated my post again. I hope this time it is the good one. I think the mistake will be here `L8035.145      ` because there are some spaces in it.  And when it tries to read it as integer it throws the error.

Comment: Any idea how can I check now if it is the number above?

Comment: So did that request get the *exact* same error stack trace? It would be odd for that data to get an error for character 491... it's not clear where `Company` (as per your code sample) comes into it as that isn't mentioned in the response.

Comment: Company is the property defined by Visual studio which represents this in XML `MMITNO`. When I call it via the myconsole.exe it throws an error.

Comment: Right, well "L8035.145" definitely isn't a number... so why have you got code saying that it is? At least we now know what value it was trying to convert...